# Unknown custom element: <inertia-link> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name"

Tags: inertiajs

After I update the inertiajs in laravel project, I cannot use inertia-link in my project, it always show about error. I have no idea, I tried Link components as inertiajs mentions in their document page. Please share me you experience, thank you.

Comment: You need to describe your problem in MUCH more details for anyone to be able to help you. And include (relevant) code/configuration samples.

Comment: if you using vue js laravel this solution may work

in app.js (or main js file where you imported inertia-vue)
`import 'Link', import { createInertiaApp, Link } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue'`

then, in that js file add this line:

`Vue.component("inertia-link", Link);`